# Raise event of other class library in c#

Tags: c#

I have two class libraries say A and B. A has reference of B. so I can call any function of B. But now the need is, I want to raise event(or function; actually just want to send a little info) of A from B. I cant add reference because of circular dependency. Is there any way to do this ?

please give me code sample; how to register and call
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define event in class B (you can use one of [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegates for event):

```
public class B
{
    public event Action<int> SomethingHappened; // define event

    private void Something()
    {
        if (SomethingHappened != null) // check if somebody subscribed
            SomethingHappened(42); // raise event and pass data
    }
}
```

And subscribe to that event in class A:

```
public class A
{
   private B _b;

   public A(B b)
   {
      _b = b;
      _b.SomethingHappened += SomethingHappenedWithB; // subscribe
   }

   private void SomethingHappenedWithB(int data)
   {
       // handle event, use data
   }
}
```

Consider reading [C# Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: While it'll work with `Action<int>` it's better (by convention) to use `EventHandler<SomeEventArgs>`, where `SomeEventArgs` inherits from `EventArgs`. Also, instead of `Something` you should use `OnSomethingHappened`.

Comment: @JeffRSon it's better when you are working with WinForms (or other infrastructure which uses EventHandlers for events) but with plain domain classes that is overkill. If I don't need to pass sender to subscribers, then I will not add this functionality. Also passing `EventArgs.Empty` is really odd. I always try to follow YAGNI principle

Comment: @JeffRSon I do know about OnSomethingHappened and that it should be virtual protected, but again for simple case without inheritance it's not required